# wcf data services self hosted credential

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, impersonation

I'm currently implementing RESTful services via WCF Data Services (System.Data.Services).
My RESTful service is hosted in a window service. There is no IIS involved.

The service is working fine except that it cannot connect to my sql database as it requires impersonation.

In a normal WCF service I'm able to impersonate by accessing the WindowsIdentity of ServiceSecurityContext. Unfortunately, the ServiceSecurityContext is null for WCF Data Services and I do not have httpContext since it is hosted in a window service.

My current workaround is to set a fixed credentials at my window service. While this is fine for development, it is not acceptable by production.

Is it possible to get the identity of the caller so that i can use the identity to get to sql server? and how?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:
    System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity